# Submit Button Changes Disabled Attribute

Tags: javascript, form-submit, submit-button

I have the following code:

```
btnSave.disabled = true;
btnCancel.disabled = true;
alert(btnSave.disabled + ':' + btnCancel.disabled);
alert(btnSave.disabled + ':' + btnCancel.disabled);
```

The first alert produces "true:true".  The second alert produces "false:true".  And, sure enough, the btnSave button is not disabled.  Cannot figure out why this is happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to give us a little bit more than that so we can help you out!, what are those buttons? jquery, js, custom objects?, what do you mean with '.disabled', are you talking about disabled attribute?

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4rwde8yg/1/

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be another event listener assigned to the btnSave button in another section of the code.  It was firing away, and the logic in that section of the code was flipping the disabled status, too.